# What are the valid types for Elasticsearch's word delimiter filter type table?

Tags: elasticsearch, token

[Elasticsearch's Word Delimiter filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html) has a very useful option `type_table`; it lets you turn otherwise special characters into legitimate characters for tokens.

It is, however, very sparsely documented:

```
type_table
A custom type mapping table, for example (when configured using type_table_path):
    # Map the $, %, '.', and ',' characters to DIGIT
    # This might be useful for financial data.
    $ => DIGIT
    % => DIGIT
    . => DIGIT
    \\u002C => DIGIT

    # in some cases you might not want to split on ZWJ
    # this also tests the case where we need a bigger byte[]
    # see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner
    \\u200D => ALPHANUM
```

From that example, we can discern that `DIGIT` and `ALPHANUM` are valid options to which we can map characters. What other options are there, and what do they do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer by digging down into the Lucene documentation, from which Elasticsearch is basically quoting.

The docs for [WordDelimiterFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory) linked to [this file in the Subversion repository](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/core/src/test-files/solr/collection1/conf/wdftypes.txt). It's heavily quoted by the Elasticsearch docs, but contained this additional snippet:

> A customized type mapping for WordDelimiterFilterFactory
>   the allowable types are: LOWER, UPPER, ALPHA, DIGIT, ALPHANUM, SUBWORD_DELIM